# SQL Server mirroring refuses to work. Tearing my hair out

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-mirroring

I'm trying to attempt what I thought would be a very simple process - the mirroring of a database between two MSSQL 2008 R2 servers within the same domain.

Both servers are configured similarly, and I have a database called 'archive' that I'd like to mirror. I took a full and log backup of the database on node 1 (principal) and restored this on node 2 with the WITH NORECOVERY option. The database shows up on node 2 (mirror) with `(In Recovery)` listed beside it in the GUI.

I start the Mirroring Wizard on the Principal server and configure the security. Both SQL processes on both are set to start up with the same Domain service account `DOMAIN\SQLService` and the `DOMAIN\SQLService` account exists as a Login on each server. Going through the steps to configure security, I select that I don't want a witness server (not yet, anyway) and it sets up the endpoints. Finally, when it asks what account I want to use to connect to each, I enter the `DOMAIN\SQLService` account.

The `DOMAIN\SQLService` is set as a local administrator of each node using a domain policy.

However, when I select 'Start mirroring', I receive the following error on Principal:

```
Database mirroring connection error 4 'An error occurred while receiving data: '64(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)'.' for 'TCP://node-b.fqdn.example.com:5022'.
```

and on mirror:

```
Database Mirroring login attempt failed with error: 'Connection handshake failed. An OS call failed: (8009030c) 0x8009030c(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105). State 67.'.  [CLIENT: 10.13.111.31]
```

10.13.111.31 is node B.

After having read all the documentation, I've tried a number of things and always end up with this result. I thought this would be a fairly easy process for a fairly standard setup, but apparently it's difficult.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after much sleep, checking, coffee and re-checking, I think I've found the solution.

DNS.

There were some stale A records in the DC's DNS server, which were causing Node-B to get rather confused about what pointed where. I fixed the DNS to reflect reality and hit 'go' and..... It worked! Well, actually it paused because I'd run out of disk space on Node-B, but other than that, all seems good.

Comment: I had a similar problem, a two node cluster, strangely only worked on the first node